# How to convert old lambda syntax to new lambda literal syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, lambda

How would I go about converting the following code to the new lambda literal syntax as described by [rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#lambda-multi-line)?

```
authenticate :user, lambda { |u| u.admin? } do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

I'm using Rails 4.09 and ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
authenticate :user, ->u{u.admin?} do
  mount Sidekiq::Web => '/sidekiq'
end
```

Comment: +1. I personally prefer wrapping arguments in a bracket, `->(u) {...}`, think it makes it slightly more readable

Comment: @BroiSatse You mean parenthesis. I think it is a matter of preference. I guess you know that in logic, there are both `λx.f(x)` and `λ(x).f(x)` (among some other) styles. Did you know that matz intended `->` to make it look like `λ` (distorted)?

Comment: @sawa - Naturally I agree, I've put it more to say `you can also write it like this`. About lambda thingy - awesome, never actually though about why they decided to use this weird looking arrow here. I really need to twist my brain a little to see lambda there though. :) I guess that `/\\` would make it harder to recognize regexs.